# How to cancel or manage focus of a PhotoCaptureDevice in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I had a camera app for WP7 which was able to control focus so when the user released the shutter button, focus action was properly cancelled.

Now I'm trying to migrate this app to WP8 but I can't find anywhere how to reproduce this.

Any ideas?

Best regards.

Comment: Why not use cam.CancelFocus() with CameraButtons.ShutterKeyReleased event?

Comment: CancelFocus is not a PhotoCaptureDevice method. It belongs to PhotoCamera which doesn't fulfill my needs. According to this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
"Compared to the PhotoCamera API, Windows.Phone.Media.Capture offers better managed code performance and provides methods for native code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, just in case you ever need it.

You have to use this line:

```
//Device is a PhotoCaptureDevice instance    
Device.SetProperty(KnownCameraPhotoProperties.LockedAutoFocusParameters, AutoFocusParameters.Focus);
```

This will cause the focus operation to pause.

Then, whenever you want to use the autfocus again you have to reset the locked parameter like this:

```
Device.SetProperty(KnownCameraPhotoProperties.LockedAutoFocusParameters, AutoFocusParameters.None);
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you :D